# How to implement session for intro slider which don't have layout activity

Tags: java, android, session

I want to implement session for intro slide which when after installing the app for the first time I want to appear it and for the second time kill it.. but I don't know implement it because it doesn't have layout.. and not working

**IntroActivity.java**

```
package com.gnex_tech.bugisberdagang;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import agency.tango.materialintroscreen.MaterialIntroActivity;
import agency.tango.materialintroscreen.SlideFragmentBuilder;

public class IntroActivity extends MaterialIntroActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setSkipButtonVisible();
    enableLastSlideAlphaExitTransition(true);

    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .backgroundColor(R.color.bg_screen1)
            .buttonsColor(R.color.btn_screen1)
            .image(R.drawable.welcome_slider_1)
            .title(getString(R.string.intro_title1))
            .description(getString(R.string.intro_desc_title1))
            .build());

    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .backgroundColor(R.color.bg_screen2)
            .buttonsColor(R.color.btn_screen2)
            .image(R.drawable.welcome_slider_2)
            .title(getString(R.string.intro_title2))
            .description(getString(R.string.intro_desc_title2))
            .build());

    addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .backgroundColor(R.color.bg_screen3)
            .buttonsColor(R.color.btn_screen3)
            .image(R.drawable.welcome_slider_3)
            .title(getString(R.string.intro_title3))
            .description(getString(R.string.intro_desc_title3))
            .build());
}


@Override
public void onFinish() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

and **Session.java**

```
package com.gnex_tech.bugisberdagang;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

/**
* Created by KurnhyGNEX on 26/12/2017.
*/

public class Session {
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Context _context;

// shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Shared preferences file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "snow-intro-slider";

private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH = "IsFirstTimeLaunch";

public Session(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}



public void setFirstTimeLaunch(boolean isFirstTime) {
    editor.putBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, isFirstTime);
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean isFirstTimeLaunch() {
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, true);
}
```

}

when I insert this code in IntroActivity.java after super.onCreate

```
session = new Session(this);
    if (!session.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
        launchHomeScreen();
        finish();
    }
private void launchHomeScreen() {
    session.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

it's not working, please give me some advice

Comment: post your error log

Answer (score 0):

**i have tried this , and it is working code :**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Button btnSkip, btnNext;
    private PrefManager prefManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
        if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
            launchHomeScreen();
            finish();
        }

        // Making notification bar transparent
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
        btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

        // layouts of all welcome sliders
        // add few more layouts if you want
        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.welcome_slider_one,
                R.layout.welcome_slider_two,
                R.layout.welcome_slider_three,
                R.layout.welcome_slider_four};

        // adding bottom dots
        addBottomDots(0);

        // making notification bar transparent
        changeStatusBarColor();

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

        btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // checking for last page
                // if last page home screen will be launched
                int current = getItem(+1);
                if (current < layouts.length) {
                    // move to next screen
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                } else {
                    launchHomeScreen();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
        dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

        int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
        int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
        }

        if (dots.length > 0)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
        startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }


    //  viewpager change listener
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            addBottomDots(position);

            // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
            if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
                // last page. make button text to GOT IT
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // still pages are left
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };

    /**
     * Making notification bar transparent
     */
    private void changeStatusBarColor() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * View pager adapter
     */
    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_welcome.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dots_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dots_margin_bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/layoutDots"
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/skip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PrefManager class**

```
public class PrefManager {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "welcome";

    private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH = "IsFirstTimeLaunch";

    public PrefManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setFirstTimeLaunch(boolean isFirstTime) {
        editor.putBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, isFirstTime);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isFirstTimeLaunch() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using other dependency bro.. 
I've used the dependencies you used in my previous app, and this is new intro i want to implement it with material design.. I think this is cool.. you must try that.. this is link [link](https://github.com/TangoAgency/material-intro-screen)